# KnownFolders that match File Explorer

Tags: c#, windows-explorer, known-folders

On the tree view of my File Explorer (formerly Windows Explorer) on Windows 10... I have a number of folders at the root... in my case this includes "Quick access", "DropBox", "OneDrive", "SharePoint", "This PC", and "Network".

Is there a KnownFolder that contains these things... or some way to get a list of folders that would match what comes up on the left of the File Explorer?

Comment: There are also some GUIDs representing some  "missing" KnownFolders like My Music

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/98d15984-12d9-47d1-a14d-6e887bf88333/how-to-get-quick-access-folder-path-in-windows-10-using-clsid-in-c-wpf-?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @RufusL in that article it talks about "shell:::{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}"... this just gets you the "This PC" part... good start though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a known folder for the namespace root used by Explorer, you might have to build the list yourself.

Look for CLSID keys with a [`System.Is.PinnedToNameSpaceTree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/props-system-ispinnedtonamespacetree) DWORD value != 0.

> Identifies whether a shell folder is pinned to the navigation pane.

[This article](https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-tip-remove-onedrive-quick-access-homegroup-and-network-icons-from-navigation-pane-of-this-pc/) indicates that the `SFGAO_NONENUMERATED` attribute might also be relevant.